# npm ERR! Object for dependency "fsevents" is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I am getting folowing error while installing anything through npm. Kindly help me with it.

premnath@premnath-Inspiron-5559:~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
[sudo] password for premnath:
npm ERR! Object for dependency "fsevents" is empty.
npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/premnath/.npm/_logs/2020-10-15T07_45_49_290Z-debug.log
premnath@premnath-Inspiron-5559:~$

node version : v12.19.0
npm version : 6.14.8[image]

Comment: Have you tried `npm rebuild fsevents`?

Comment: yeah, but I am getting same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm
> install"

Clear out `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` and run `npm i`